# Delete duplicate words in a big text file - Java

Tags: java, text, set, java-8

I have text file with a size of over 50gb.
Now i want to delete the duplicate words.
But I have heard, that i need very much RAM to load every Word from the text file into an Hash Set.
Can you tell me a very good way to delete every duplicate word from the text file?
The Words are sorted by a white space, like this.

```
word1 word2 word3 ... ...
```

Comment: What does *"sorted by whitespace"* mean???

Comment: If you are trying to use `BufferedReader` or `FileReader` then Yes, there is a performance hit because capacity of your file. So you have to try to do it with `RandomAccessFile`, it lets you to access file from various points. Check [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/randomaccessfile.html) also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560941/deleting-a-record-using-random-access-file)

Comment: How many different words are you expecting to be in the file? If nearly all words in the file are unique you won't be able to store them in memory but if there are only a few different words you should be Ok using a hash set.

Comment: This could be done by buffering the words in a database - resulting in a lot of disk I/O and query time spent when processing the file. Is that an acceptable solution to your problem?

Comment: How can i buffer them in a database ?

Comment: Is this a one-time fix or are you asking how to automate it in Java?

Answer (score 3):

The H2 answer is good, but maybe overkill.  All the words in the english language won't be more than a few Mb.  Just use a set.  You could use this in RAnders00 program.

```
public static void read50Gigs(String fileLocation, String newFileLocation) {
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<>();
    try(FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileInputStream);) {

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String nextWord = scanner.next();
            words.add(nextWord);
        }
        System.out.println("words size "+words.size());
        Files.write(Paths.get(newFileLocation), words, 
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

As an estimate of common words, I added this for war and peace (from gutenberg)

```
public static void read50Gigs(String fileLocation, String newFileLocation) {
    try {
        Set<String> words = Files.lines(Paths.get("war and peace.txt"))
                .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z\\s]", ""))
                .flatMap(Pattern.compile("\\s")::splitAsStream)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        System.out.println("words size " + words.size());//22100
        Files.write(Paths.get("out.txt"), words,
                StandardOpenOption.CREATE, 
                StandardOpenOption.TRUNCATE_EXISTING,
                StandardOpenOption.WRITE);

    } catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

It completed in 0 seconds.  You can't use `Files.lines` unless your huge source file has line breaks.  With line breaks, it will process it line by line so it won't use too much memory.

Comment: This is definitely not true - all forms/variants of all (consider a dictionary) words of the english language definitely require more storage. This is exactly what OP wanted to avoid.

Comment: @RAnders00 OED ~ 200k words, 5 char avg = 1mb (2mb using utf-16).

Comment: Sorry - looks like I got the math wrong :( My vote is locked but if it werent i'd revoke it.

Comment: No worries.  I always underestimate the power of modern computers.

Comment: “War and Peace”, like any ordinary book will have plenty of line breaks. Without them, processing the input “line by line” can become heavy. Besides that, `s->Arrays.stream(s.split("\\s"))` creates a copy of the entire line contents. Use `Pattern.compile("\\s")::splitAsStream` instead. And don’t use `.forEach(s -> words.add(s))`, use `collect(Collectors.toSet())` or, if you just want to count the distinct words, use `.distinct().count()`…

Comment: As an addendum, if the RAM space required by the unique words really becomes too big, implementing a custom key class might help, i.e. for matching case insensitive English words, you need at most only 5 bits per character, rather than 16. Only if that not helps, I’d consider expensive database operations (after trying to buy more RAM)…

Comment: @Holger, The `.distinct().count()` is actually has roughly the same efficiency as `.collect(toSet()).size()` as both use `HashSet` internally to store all the elements.

Comment: @brian: the expression to the left of the `::` operator is evaluated once and its result captured. So you don’t need to store the pattern into a variable (unless you use a `static` variable to reuse the pattern throughout multiple method invocations)…

Comment: @Tagir Valeev: That’s right for the current implementation but only by using the appropriate terminal operation clarifying your intention, you allow alternative implementations or different future versions…

Answer (score 0):

This approach uses a database to buffer the words found.

It also assumes that words - regardless of case - are equal.

The H2 documentation states that a database on a non-FAT filesystem has a maximum size of [4 TB](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#limits_limitations) (using the default page size of 2KB), which is more than enough for this purpose.

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class H2WordReading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//        read50Gigs("50gigfile.txt", "cleaned50gigfile.txt");
        read50Gigs("./testSmallFile", "./cleaned");
    }

    public static void read50Gigs(String fileLocation, String newFileLocation) {
        try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:./words");
             FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileLocation);
             Scanner scanner = new Scanner(fileInputStream);
             FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFileLocation);
             OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream)) {
            connection.createStatement().execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS WORDS;");
            connection.createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE WORDS(WORD VARCHAR NOT NULL);");

            PreparedStatement insertStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO WORDS VALUES (?);");
            PreparedStatement queryStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM WORDS WHERE UPPER(WORD) = UPPER(?);");

            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                String nextWord = scanner.next();
                queryStatement.setString(1, nextWord);
                ResultSet resultSet = queryStatement.executeQuery();
                if (!resultSet.next())  // word not found, ok
                {
                    outputStreamWriter.write(scanner.hasNext() ? (nextWord + ' ') : nextWord);
                    insertStatement.setString(1, nextWord);
                    insertStatement.execute();
                } // word found, just don't write anything
            }

        } catch (IOException | SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

You need to add the [H2 driver jar](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter/com.h2database%3Ah2/view) present on the classpath.

Note that I only tested this with a small file consisting of 10 words or so. You should try this attempt with your 50 gigabyte file and report back any errors.

Please be aware that this attempt

- normalizes all whitespace and newlines down to a single space character
- always uses the first occurrence of a word and deletes all upcoming occurences

The time this attempt takes scales exponentially with the amount of words in the file.

Comment: Doesn’t h2 support declaring the contents of a column `DISTINCT`? That could avoid the exponential scaling…

Comment: Does it? Doesn't H2 need to see in the table whether the key is already duplicated (and therefore look through the whole table, or how does it work)?

Comment: I’d hope that it supports some sort of hashing or binary tree to avoid `O(n)` complexity for something it then knows to be needed for every insertion attempt. But I don’t know whether h2 supports all this, but since database are supposed to do such things in general, I just asked…

Comment: How can I add the H2 driver jar ? Just download the h2-1.4.190.jar and put it in the folder with my .class files ?

Comment: @Human Usually, you have to go to the settings in your IDE and configure it as a library. Just google "<Your IDE> library jar" and find instructions that way.

Comment: This worked. But i tried it first with a 100mb text file and it takes up to an hour. Can i make something that it works much faster?

Comment: @Human see the other answer just using a Set http://stackoverflow.com/a/33323127/4464702

Comment: This works only if my result text file would be some mb. But i have already tried it using a set. It occurs a error that i dont have enough ram.

Comment: @Human Today I used the H2 Database engine and I was able to write 100000 rows into the database in ~10 seconds, are you running on a really really old machine? In which case software is not going to help you - you might need to upgrade your hardware then.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Remove duplicate words from a file
    public String removeDupsFromFile(String str) {
        String[] words = str.split(" ");
        LinkedHashMap<String, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

        for (int i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i++) {
            if (map.containsKey(words[i])) {
                int count = map.get(words[i]) + 1;
                map.put(words[i], count);
            } else {
                map.put(words[i], 1);
            }
        }

        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
        Iterator itr = map.keySet().iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            result.append(itr.next() + " ");

        }
        return result.toString();
    }
```